# Using a commit midway through an interactive rebase when rerere is not on

Tags: git, dvcs, git-rerere

So if I am using `git rebase -i -p <commit>` on a topic branch and there is a merge commit in between somewhere which I am expected to redo by git. But the last time I did that merge commit it was pretty hairy and made quite a few changes to support a big fix in the other branch. I did not have rerere on.

I used a `git cherry-pick -n <merge commit> -p <parent number>` in the middle of a rebase and it worked. I just had to say `git checkout --theirs` for everything to resolve the conflicts.

But I was wondering whether we can run rerere midway through an interactive rebase? Also is there a good alternative to use instead of rerere?